# Small Mac-based post house looking to run a Windows box, but we rely on some Python scripts

Tags: python, windows, pip, macports, easy-install

You can tell where this is going from the title..

I work at a small post house, and to replace one of our older Mac Pros, we were looking at building a mid-range PC (doesn't need to do much heavy lifting - not worth the price of a new Mac Pro)..
The problem is, we have a number of scripts that we use for footage transcoding and media management, and they were coded for our Mac-exclusive environment..
The basic procedure for setting up a new workstation is:

Install pip using easy_install

Use pip to install:

youtube_dl

pexpect

parsedatetime

XlsxWriter

Install MacPorts..  Use MacPorts to install ffmpeg, lftp, and ImageMagick.  From there, install a couple custom in-house scripts (that rely mostly on the preceding dependencies and python 2.7 (via xcode).

I'm NOT going to ask how to adapt this to PC, since that would be way outside the scope of a single question. My question is, without a strong python developer on-site (the custom scripts were written years ago by someone who's no longer with the company), is it even feasible to adapt the install scripts to a PC environment?  We have a freelance Python developer that we consult for minor script changes and he wasn't sure (his response was "I would first double check to make sure some of the utilities can even run on windows. I’m not 100% sure they can or not").  Do any of the utilities jump out as something that would not be adaptable to a Windows environment?

Thanks very much in advance - I know it's a rather broad question.

Comment: Python runs on Windows.

Comment: Might be worth checking out chocolatey as a package manager for windows.  You might have troubles with differences in directory structure but that could be worked around either by setting up the directory structure on the PC to match or by rewriting the app.  The libraries all look like they're windows-compatible.

Comment: For this kind of work, as long as I don't need a GUI, I tend to use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) (available in Windows 10 Anniversary Update and later). It provides almost every functionality of a Linux machine (with some exceptions, of course), and it's easy to run on Windows because it's built in. So if you're not doing anything graphical (and even if you are, there are X servers available), with WSL you can do things almost as you've always done them, because Linux :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the suggestions.  I'll bring them up to our Python guy when we next speak.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you "don't need heavy lifting", why upset your workflow this way?

If you are determined to buy a PC, why not run Linux on it rather than Windows?  The setup process you described will be almost exactly the same on a Linux machine except for involving a different package manager instead of MacPorts.

Craig
PS the Python modules you listed are all available via MacPorts.  It would simplify the software management process to install everything that way.

Comment: Mainly for the money-saving.  We just purchased a new MacPro for another edit room, and don't really have it in the budget for a second one at the moment, but at the same time, they're eager to replace this 9 year old MacPro that I'm on now (I know, a bit of a catch 22).
  
We've already purchased a copy of Windows (which could of course be returned), but as far as the Linux idea, would Niayesh's idea above (running Windows Subsystem for Linux) allow effectively the same operability in a Windows environment?

Comment: Since you don't seem to be a Windows shop, I would think it would be simpler to just run Linux rather than Linux as a Windows subsystem.  Or buy a Mac Mini (maybe a refurb) and avoid the learning curves of new operating systems.

Comment: So part of the backstory that I left out cause I didn't see it coming up: I'm relatively new to the job (4 mos), and I'm a PC guy through and through. I hate OSX. They knew this, and insisted on hiring me anyway, and at the first opportunity, told me to replace my [dying] Mac with this custom build, so I'm the one who broke the news to them about the Python scripts, and get to solve the problem about how to run them. I'm MUCH faster on Windows than on OSX. Even after years using OSX elsewhere it's just never been intuitive to me at all; the more I use it the more I dislike it. So there's that.